# Make a change on a dropdown, wait for triggered event, then make more changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu

I have two `select` drop-down menus, `.aselect` and `.bselect`. I have a `change` event on `.aselect` to make an API call and update the options on `.bselect` and that works.

```
// works as expected
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.aselect').change(function(){
        // make API call
        // update .bselect options appropriately
    });
});
```

That piece works as expected.

However, when I try to use jQuery to select an option in `.aselect` and then also select an expected option in the resulting `.bselect`, it seems like the API request doesn't complete before the attempt to select the option in `.bselect` and so it isn't there and nothing is selected.

```
    $(function() {
        $(".aselect").val('firstvalue').change();
        $(".bselect").val('secondvalue').change();
    });
```

The option `firstvalue` in `.aselect` is selected, the API call does complete correctly, and `.bselect` is populated with the expected options (including `'secondvalue'`). But the `secondvalue` option is **not** selected.

I've tried a number of permutations of `.done` and `.promise` things, but can't get one that produces the desired results.

How do I wait for the API call to finish processing after changing the option for `.aselect` before trying to change the option for `.bselect`?

Comment: Have you tried chaining `.then()` to your API call? Could you demonstrate with at least some minimal code how you're handling the api call?

Comment: If I do that, am I committed to doing the `.then()` every time the client changes the options? Because I think I don't want to do that.

My second block of code is supposed to initialize the menus on page load. Once the client makes their own changes to the menus, the API calls should still work and muck with the option values as planned.

Comment: Technically yes. If you're awaiting for Promise to resolve then absolutely you'll want to await the response. Isn't that your question?

Comment: I want the wait to happen the one time that `$(".aselect").val('firstvalue').change();` is called, and at no other times.

Comment: Then you'll want to bind one-time logic inside your chained `.then` callback including binding your change event.

Comment: OK. So let's say that's what I wanted to do. What does it look like?

Comment: @wckronholm: you can call API with async: false, but maybe it can lock your process.

Comment: @jimmy I'm using `$.getJSON` now. Am I right that I would need to change it to `$.ajax` to be able to try `async: false`?

Comment: @wckronholm: right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I refactored my code.

The API call is now a standalone function with a `return $.ajax()` at the end. Now when I use it, I can either `.done()` or not, depending on what I need.